# Fill remaining height in fixed-height css table

Tags: html, css

I've trying to get a layout where a a fixed-height table with two rows, the first scaling to the its content, and the second being the remaining height, and keeping its contents inside it. The height of the bottom part needs to be 'real' (not clipped by a parent or anything), such that it could have overflow: scroll, or children of height: 100%, etc.

This is what it should look like:

[image: Image description, yo]

**I got it working in Chrome**, using an absolutely positioned div inside a relative table-cell:

http://jsfiddle.net/9FPqx/

The core of it:

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="absolute-fill">
            Stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.row
{
    display: table-row;
}

.cell
{
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
}

.absolute-fill
{
    position: absolute
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

With another intermediary relative div between the table-cell and the content (rather than setting relative on the table-cell itself), **it works in Firefox**:

http://jsfiddle.net/sXHry/

It does **not work in IE**. I need IE >= 9.

It seems like IE thinks the relative element with absolute child has no content height, and so gives it 0 height.

I feel like I'm so close but so far. Is there a way of solving this with just html and css? Am I on the wrong track using display: table? Or should I give up and just throw some javascript at it?

Comment: Have you tried using the developer tools in IE to find out why the divs are not showing? You can try to add something like this to your CSS to help debugging: `* {border: 1px dotted gray; margin: 2px; padding: 2px;}`

Comment: IE will give the relative element 0 height. It seems to think that a relative table-cell element (or relative child of a table-cell), with an absolute child, has no content height.

Answer (score 2):

Why does it need to be a table? Can't you just let the container hide the overflow?

#### html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">
        Top, green area
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        Bottom, blue area
    </div>
</div>
```

#### css

```
.container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 162px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightblue;
}
.top {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sXHry/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/sXHry/2/ (less content)

I suspect i might be missing something, looking forward to being enlightened ;)

Comment: I'll clarify the question a bit. The problem with this approach is that the bottom section is _not_ actually the height it appears to be. Its height needs to be its own, so that contents could be set to 100% height or the it could be set to overflow: scroll.